# Split a continous string (without space) with some length using JS

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need to split a continous string without spaces into two or more parts based on the length provided.

To split a string for ex:"1123071271231231231212730123071293790123017231027301273465", I am using the below regex

```
data.match(new RegExp('(?:^|\\b)[\\w\\W .]{1,48}(?:|$)', 'gi'))
```

But this doesn't split it correctly.

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sp6zhkfa/3/

I need to split the above string into two parts based on {1,48} length . This length varies dynamically based on some calculated values so my regex will be actually like

```
data.match(new RegExp('(?:^|\\b)[\\w\\W .]{1,' + splitChar + '}(?:|$)', 'gi'))
```

where splitChar is a dynamically calculated value which is 48 in the above example.

Can anyone suggest me on this?

Comment: string slice, substr, substring ... any of them probably a better choice for what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let splitChar = 48; // your calculated value
let vals = [];
for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i += splitChar) {
    vals.push(data.substr(i, splitChar));
}
```

Then you have an array of all parts in `vals`

Answer (score 0):

`\b`, `\W` and `$` are irrelevant, as you have a single continuous string. Find their meaning [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Use either `\w` to match any alphanumeric character, or `\d` to match only numeric characters.

The regex looks simple:

```js
data.match(new RegExp('\\w{1,' + splitChar + '}', 'gi'))
```